# Development tools for Adobe Flex/AIR?

Tags: apache-flex

I'm starting a new development position with a company that implements many of its products in Adobe Flex.  What tools should I look to install (Ubuntu Linux options prefered) for Flex development?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As dirkgently said, installing Flex Builder 3 in Linux is a great way to get going.  It's quick and easy to get up and running, and since it's based on Eclipse, the overall environment is decent.

That said, I was able to put together a decent Flex-building environment using [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) and some third-party packages to get everything running under Linux.

Here's a quick rundown of what I used (this isn't comprehensive--just what I can remember):

- [Flex 3 SDK](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/flexdownloads/) for Linux
- [actionscript-mode.el](http://blog.pettomato.com/?p=12) for AS code
  highlighting
- [nxml bundle](http://www.thaiopensource.com/nxml-mode/) for MXML code
  highlighting
- [ani-fcsh.el](http://anirudhs.chaosnet.org/code/ani-fcsh.el.html) for running fcsh
  from Emacs
- [ECB](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/) for code browsing in Emacs
- [snippet.el](http://www.kazmier.com/computer/snippet.el) for creating code
  templates in Emacs

[This link](http://flexman.info/2008/09/22/setup-flash-flex-development-evironment-under-unix-linux/) was also helpful for getting started.  It links to [this article](http://ntt.cc/2008/05/19/using-actionscript-3-to-develop-adobe-flash-content-on-linux.html) which talks about putting together a Flex development environment in Linux.  I was able to put together some shell scripts for compiling and running applications.

Note: I didn't do any debugging, though Adobe has some [info](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=debugging_01.html) about it.

Note #2: If you decide to use Flex Builder, it will install the Flash Player 9 debugger version in your browser (you can tell it not to).  I would recommend installing [version 10's debugger](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html).  The builder will output a warning about not supporting the version, but everything else appears to work.

Comment: There are also Emacs plugins for working with SVN.  I haven't used them, but they're also work looking into.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, try [Flex Builder 3 alpha for Linux](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flexbuilder_linux.html). That's the you can get (not without its set of pet peeves though!). It lacks the following however:

```
* Design view
* States view
* Refactoring
* Data Wizards
* Cold Fusion - Data Services Wizard
* Web Services introspection
* Profiler
```

Since AIR/Flex are cross-platform technologies, I don't see why you want to limit yourself to Linux. At least for the time being, I think you are better off with the proper Flex Builder 3 on Windows for development. You can then test your product(s) on Linux.

Comment: The reason I say Ubuntu Linux is because I found out already that Ubuntu will be my dev environment.

Comment: Adobe will no longer be investing in the development of a version of Adobe® Flex® Builder™ or Adobe Flash® Builder™ that runs on Linux operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

about debugging - there is an external AIR debugger called MonsterDebugger which is pretty good